# Passing generic event to Guava EventBus?

Tags: java, swing, generics, reflection, guava

I've become very fond of Google Gauva's EventBus, so much that I want to include it in one of my Swing [GridBagBuilder](http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.com/2015/01/gridbagbuilder-wrapping-gridbaglayout.html) API's. The goal is to take a Swing component and do something with it in an arbitrary event, and subscribe this to an EventBus. The problem is I think the reflection operations done by the EventBus are not liking my generics for any arbitrary event type.

Essentially, the method accepts a BiConsumer where C is a Swing Component and E is an arbitrary event type to subscribe to EventBus.

```
public <E> void subscribe(EventBus eventBus, BiConsumer<C,E> consumer) { 
    eventBus.register(new Object() { 
        @Subscribe
        public void processEvent(E event) { 
            try { 
            consumer.accept(comp, event);
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
   });
}
```

The event bus seems to be working but I keep getting bizarre `ClassCastException` errors. Is there any way I can make this work? Or is what I'm trying to achieve a lost cause?

UPDATE: Here is an SSCCE. It breaks when there are multiple event types, and somewhere the generics and internal reflection mechanisms get messed up and it can't distinguish one event type from another.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus;
import com.google.common.eventbus.Subscribe;

public class EventBusTest<C extends Component> {
    private final C comp;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final EventBus eventBus = new EventBus();

        EventBusTest<JButton> test = new EventBusTest<>(new JButton("Hello"));
        test.subscribe(eventBus, (JButton c, SomeEvent e) -> System.out.println("Hello"));
        test.subscribe(eventBus, (JButton c, SomeOtherEvent e) -> System.out.println("World"));

        eventBus.post(new SomeEvent());
    }

    private EventBusTest(C comp) { 
        this.comp = comp;
    }
    public<E> void subscribe(EventBus eventBus, BiConsumer<C,E> consumer) { 
        eventBus.register(new Object() { 
            @Subscribe
            public void processEvent(E event) { 
                try { 
                consumer.accept(comp, event);
                } catch (Exception e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
       });
    }

    private static final class SomeEvent {}
    private static final class SomeOtherEvent {}
}
```

And here is the console print...

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.swa.rm.pricing.EventBusTest$SomeEvent cannot be cast to com.swa.rm.pricing.EventBusTest$SomeOtherEvent
    at com.swa.rm.pricing.EventBusTest$$Lambda$14/28594521.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.swa.rm.pricing.EventBusTest$1.processEvent(EventBusTest.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at com.swa.rm.pricing.EventBusTest.main(EventBusTest.java:21)
Hello
```

Comment: Please show a complete and reproducible example that demonstrates a `ClassCastException` and post the full stack trace.

Comment: Dang it, the SSCCE I built is working. Why...?

Comment: Okay got it in a broken state! It breaks when there are multiple event types. Updating above...

Comment: What is interesting here is I only posted a SomeEvent, which it successfully injected to the SomeEvent subscriber. But it also injected to the SomeOtherEvent subscriber and proceeded to try casting the SomeEvent to a SomeOtherEvent. I think the reflection voodoo behind EventBus is becoming apparent, and the generic event parameters are wreaking havoc.

Comment: This looks like there's no way Guava could possibly make this work because type erasure.

Comment: Even with Mr. Prydens solution below? Reflection allows some facility of un-doing erasure i think, doesn't it?

Comment: @ThomasN.: Reflection does not allow you to "undo erasure", definitely not in the general case. My suggestion is to use a type token to essentially reify the type manually, which will require you to type check it and not call the callback unless the type matches. Louis is right that Guava couldn't do this itself because the code needs to be in your subscriber object. (And, as a meta-comment: when it comes to Guava questions, you're unlikely to get a more authoritative answer than from Louis, as he is one of the Guava maintainers, so what he says is probably right.)

Comment: Alright then. I guess its alright since EventBus looks to be designed to do nearly all things well, but not all things. Its a minor convenience I was building anyway, and definitely not a project-killer. Thanks for your help Louis and Daniel, I'm glad you make time to answer questions here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type parameter `E` in your anonymous `Object` subclass in `subscribe()` will always be erased, since there is no concrete type to reify it. The erasure of `E` is just `Object`, so nothing prevents your `processEvent()` method from being called with any type.

To fix this, you'll need to pass a type token (`Class<E>` will probably suffice) and use it to check that the runtime type is actually `E` before invoking the `BiConsumer` callback.